# How to loop through scraping multiple documents on multiple web pages using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am interested in grabbing text from a webpage of a medical documents for a Natural Language Processing project.  The web page document text that I am scraping was not designed with any semantic markup, it's just a big blob of text with bold headings. After getting some help and starting with the first page I am interested in I've implemented the following code to grab the document text from the web page:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString, Comment

url = 'https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24- Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal%20Abscess%20I&D'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

title_el = soup.find('h1')
page_title = title_el.text.strip()
first_hr = title_el.find_next_sibling('hr')

description_title = title_el.find_next_sibling('b', 
text=re.compile('description', flags=re.I))
description_text_parts = []
for s in description_title.next_siblings:
    if s is first_hr:
        break
    if isinstance(s, Tag):
        description_text_parts.append(s.text.strip())
    elif isinstance(s, NavigableString):
        description_text_parts.append(str(s).strip())
description_text = '\n'.join(p for p in description_text_parts if p.strip())

# titles are all bold and uppercase
titles = [b for b in first_hr.find_next_siblings('b') if b.text.strip().isupper()]

docs = []
for t in titles:
    text_parts = []
    for s in t.next_siblings:
        # go until next title
        if s in titles:
            break
        if isinstance(s, Comment):
            continue
        if isinstance(s, Tag):
            if s.name == 'div':
                break
            text_parts.append(s.text.strip())
        elif isinstance(s, NavigableString):
            text_parts.append(str(s).strip())
    text = '\n'.join(p for p in text_parts if p.strip())
    docs.append({
        'title': t.text.strip(),
        'text': text
    })
```

This will add my document text as a dictionary separated by `title` field keys and `text` values to a list named `docs`.  At this point the web page that was scraped in the above example would be the only element in the `docs` list.

I am interested in creating a loop to add all medical document records in the Gastroenterology section from the web page found at https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/browse.asp?type=24-Gastroenterology&page=1.  There are 23 separate pages each with a number of different medical documents in alphabetical order containing a total of 230 medical documents.  I am wondering what the best way to perform this loop would be?  Again, my goal would be to append each medical document to the `docs` list as shown for the first example in my previous code.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For a robust solution, you can use a `while` loop to continuously iterate over the links as long as the "next" (`>`) button is present. At each iteration, you can scrape the next page and extract the headers with the link and description for use later:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def parse_page(_d):
   data = filter(lambda x:x != '\n', [i for i in _d.find('table', {'id':'Browse'}).td.contents if isinstance(i, str) or i.name == 'a'])
   _next = next(data, None)
   while _next is not None:
      new_d, _n = {'title':_next.text, 'link':_next['href']}, next(data, None)
      if hasattr(_n, 'text'):
         yield new_d
         yield {'title':_n.text, 'link':_n['href'], 'about':next(data)}
      else:
         yield {**new_d, 'about':_n}   
      _next = next(data, None)  

d, r = soup(requests.get('https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/browse.asp?type=24-Gastroenterology&page=1').text, 'html.parser'), []
r.append(list(parse_page(d)))
_c = [i for i in d.find('div', {'class':'Contrast'}).find_all('a') if i.text == '>']
while _c:
   d = soup(requests.get(f'https://www.mtsamples.com{_c[0]["href"]}').text, 'html.parser')
   r.append(list(parse_page(d)))
   _c = [i for i in d.find('div', {'class':'Contrast'}).find_all('a') if i.text == '>']
```

Output (first element of `r`, due to SO's character limit):

```
[{'title': 'Abdominal Abscess I&D;', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal Abscess I&D', 'about': 'Incision and drainage (I&D;) of abdominal abscess, excisional debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and muscle, then removal of foreign body.'}, {'title': 'Abdominal Exploration', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2038-Abdominal Exploration', 'about': 'Congenital chylous ascites and chylothorax and rule out infradiaphragmatic lymphatic leak.   Diffuse intestinal and mesenteric lymphangiectasia.  '}, {'title': 'Abdominal Pain - Consult', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=1921-Abdominal Pain - Consult', 'about': 'The patient presented to the emergency room last evening with approximately 7- to 8-day history of abdominal pain which has been persistent.'}, {'title': 'Abscess Excision', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2330-Abscess Excision', 'about': 'Excision of abscess, removal of foreign body.  Repair of incisional hernia.  Recurrent re-infected sebaceous cyst of abdomen.  Abscess secondary to retained foreign body and incisional hernia.'}, {'title': 'Admission History & Physical - Nausea', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=1152-Admission History & Physical - Nausea', 'about': 'Patient status post gastric bypass surgery, developed nausea and right upper quadrant pain.'}, {'title': 'Adrenalectomy & Umbilical Hernia Repair', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2464-Adrenalectomy & Umbilical Hernia Repair', 'about': 'Laparoscopic hand-assisted left adrenalectomy and umbilical hernia repair.  Patient with a 5.5-cm diameter nonfunctioning mass in his right adrenal.'}, {'title': 'Air Under Diaphragm - Consult', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2166-Air Under Diaphragm - Consult', 'about': 'Possible free air under the diaphragm.  On a chest x-ray for what appeared to be shortness of breath she was found to have what was thought to be free air under the right diaphragm.  No intra-abdominal pathology.'}, {'title': 'Appendectomy', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=1975-Appendectomy', 'about': 'Appendicitis, nonperforated.  Appendectomy.  A transverse right lower quadrant incision was made directly over the point of maximal tenderness. '}, {'title': 'Appendectomy - 1', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2298-Appendectomy - 1', 'about': 'Acute appendicitis, gangrenous.  Appendectomy.'}, {'title': 'Appendectomy - Laparoscopic ', 'link': '/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2728-Appendectomy - Laparoscopic ', 'about': 'Laparoscopic appendectomy and peritoneal toilet and photos.  Pelvic inflammatory disease and periappendicitis.'}]
```

Comment: This is a good first solution, however, I am interested in scraping the individual documents within each page rather than the page themselves.  For example, there are 23 separate pages each with 10 different medical documents (found within each link) given in alphabetical order for a total of 230 medical documents.  I would like to append a list of the 230 records containing the text of each medical document.  I can see that `r` is length 23 and provides the contents for each separate web page, however, the next step would be to scrape each individual document from this and append a list.

Comment: @JakeNiederer You can certainly scrape the documents, this solution provides a link to each page for you to query and parse.

Answer (score 0):

simply find all the pagination urls, then walk all those pages, find document urls and extract the documents. Here's a full-fledged solution for you.

This will walk pages concurrently and extract documents from all pages in batches

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, Comment, NavigableString
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from pprint import pprint
import itertools
import concurrent
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

BASE_URL = 'https://www.mtsamples.com'


def make_soup(url: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    res = requests.get(url)
    res.raise_for_status()
    html = res.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def make_soup_parallel(urls: list) -> list:
    workers = min(10, len(urls))
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as e:
        return list(e.map(make_soup, urls))


def find_pagination_urls(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list:
    urls = set()
    for a in soup.select('.Contrast a'):
        if not a.text.isnumeric():
            continue
        url = urljoin(BASE_URL, a['href'])
        urls.add(url)
    return sorted(list(urls), key=lambda u: int(u.split('page=')[1]))


def find_document_urls(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list:
    urls = []
    for a in soup.select('#Browse a'):
        url = urljoin(BASE_URL, a['href'])
        urls.append(url)
    return urls


def find_all_doc_urls() -> list:
    index_url = 'https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/browse.asp?type=24-Gastroenterology&page=1'
    index_soup = make_soup(index_url)

    next_pages = find_pagination_urls(index_soup)
    doc_urls = []
    for soup in make_soup_parallel(next_pages):
        doc_urls.extend(find_document_urls(index_soup))
    return doc_urls


def extract_docs(soup: BeautifulSoup) -> list:
    title_el = soup.find('h1')
    first_hr = title_el.find_next_sibling('hr')

    # titles are all bold and uppercase
    titles = [b for b in first_hr.find_next_siblings('b') if b.text.strip().isupper()]

    docs = []
    for t in titles:
        text_parts = []
        for s in t.next_siblings:
            # go until next title
            if s in titles:
                break
            if isinstance(s, Comment):
                continue
            if isinstance(s, Tag):
                if s.name == 'div':
                    break
                text_parts.append(s.text.strip())
            elif isinstance(s, NavigableString):
                text_parts.append(str(s).strip())
        text = '\n'.join(p for p in text_parts if p.strip())
        docs.append({
            'title': t.text.strip(),
            'text': text
        })
    return docs


def batch(it, n: int):
    it = [iter(it)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*it, fillvalue=None)


docs = []
doc_urls = find_all_doc_urls()

for b in batch(doc_urls, 5):
    batch_urls = list(filter(bool, b))
    for soup in make_soup_parallel(batch_urls):
        docs.extend(extract_docs(soup))
pprint(docs)
```

output:

```
[{'text': 'Abdominal wall abscess.', 'title': 'PREOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS:'},
 {'text': 'Abdominal wall abscess.', 'title': 'POSTOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS:'},
 {'text': 'Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional '
          'debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and '
          'muscle, then removal of foreign body.',
  'title': 'PROCEDURE:'},
 {'text': 'LMA.', 'title': 'ANESTHESIA:'},
...
```